# DONE key doesn't work on custom keyboard

Tags: android, custom-keyword

in my code there is a all keys work well except **DONE** so tell me suggestion of regarding to **DONE** keys.
MY CODE is below:

**my mainActivity code is below**

```
package nl.fampennings.keyboard;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    CustomKeyboard mCustomKeyboard;


    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mCustomKeyboard= new CustomKeyboard(this, R.id.keyboardview, R.xml.hexkbd);

        mCustomKeyboard.registerEditText(R.id.edittext0); 
        mCustomKeyboard.registerEditText(R.id.edittext1);
        mCustomKeyboard.registerEditText(R.id.edittext2);
        mCustomKeyboard.registerEditText(R.id.edittext3);
        mCustomKeyboard.registerEditText(R.id.edittext4);

    }

    @Override public void onBackPressed() { 
        // NOTE Trap the back key: when the CustomKeyboard is still visible hide it, only when it is invisible, finish activity 
        if( mCustomKeyboard.isCustomKeyboardVisible() ) mCustomKeyboard.hideCustomKeyboard(); else this.finish();
    }
    boolean  displayMsg(){
        boolean flag=true;
        if(flag)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "adfdf", 100).show();
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

**My Customerkeyboard.java file is below**

```
package nl.fampennings.keyboard;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard;
import android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView;
import android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
class CustomKeyboard {
    private OnKeyboardActionListener mOnKeyboardActionListener = new OnKeyboardActionListener() {

        public final static int enter = 13;
        public final static int CodeDelete   = -5; // Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE
        public final static int CodeCancel   = -3; // Keyboard.KEYCODE_CANCEL
        public final static int CodePrev     = 55000;
        public final static int CodeAllLeft  = 55001;
        public final static int CodeLeft     = 55002;
        public final static int CodeRight    = 55003;
        public final static int CodeAllRight = 55004;
        public final static int CodeNext     = 55005;
        public final static int CodeClear    = 55006;

        @Override public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
            View focusCurrent = mHostActivity.getWindow().getCurrentFocus();
            if( focusCurrent==null || focusCurrent.getClass()!=EditText.class ) return;
            EditText edittext = (EditText) focusCurrent;
            Editable editable = edittext.getText();
            int start = edittext.getSelectionStart();
            main=new MainActivity();
            // Apply the key to the edittext
            if( primaryCode==CodeCancel ) {
                hideCustomKeyboard();
            }
            else if(primaryCode==enter)
            {
                edittext.setText("");
                main.displayMsg();
            }
             else if( primaryCode==CodeDelete ) {
                if( editable!=null && start>0 ) editable.delete(start - 1, start);
               // main.displayMsg();

            } else if( primaryCode==CodeClear ) {

                if( editable!=null ) editable.clear();
            } else if( primaryCode==CodeLeft ) {
                if( start>0 ) edittext.setSelection(start - 1);
            } else if( primaryCode==CodeRight ) {
                if (start < edittext.length()) edittext.setSelection(start + 1);
            } else if( primaryCode==CodeAllLeft ) {
                edittext.setSelection(0);
            } else if( primaryCode==CodeAllRight ) {
                edittext.setSelection(edittext.length());
            } else if( primaryCode==CodePrev ) {
                View focusNew= edittext.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_BACKWARD);
                if( focusNew!=null ) focusNew.requestFocus();
            } else if( primaryCode==CodeNext ) {
                //main.displayMsg();
                View focusNew= edittext.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_FORWARD);
                if( focusNew!=null ) focusNew.requestFocus();
            } else { // insert character
                editable.insert(start, Character.toString((char) primaryCode));
            }
        }

        @Override public void onPress(int arg0) {

        }

        @Override public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {
        }

        @Override public void onText(CharSequence text) {
        }

        @Override public void swipeDown() {
        }

        @Override public void swipeLeft() {
        }

        @Override public void swipeRight() {
        }

        @Override public void swipeUp() {
        }
    };
   public CustomKeyboard(Activity host, int viewid, int layoutid) {
        mHostActivity= host;
        mKeyboardView= (KeyboardView)mHostActivity.findViewById(viewid);
        mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(new Keyboard(mHostActivity, layoutid));
        mKeyboardView.setPreviewEnabled(false); // NOTE Do not show the preview balloons
        mKeyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(mOnKeyboardActionListener);
        // Hide the standard keyboard initially
        mHostActivity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    }

    /** Returns whether the CustomKeyboard is visible. */
    public boolean isCustomKeyboardVisible() {
        return mKeyboardView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
    }

    /** Make the CustomKeyboard visible, and hide the system keyboard for view v. */
    public void showCustomKeyboard( View v ) {
        mKeyboardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mKeyboardView.setEnabled(true);
        if( v!=null ) ((InputMethodManager)mHostActivity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

    /** Make the CustomKeyboard invisible. */
    public void hideCustomKeyboard() {
        mKeyboardView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mKeyboardView.setEnabled(false);
    }

    /**
     * Register <var>EditText<var> with resource id <var>resid</var> (on the hosting activity) for using this custom keyboard.
     *
     * @param resid The resource id of the EditText that registers to the custom keyboard.
     */
    public void registerEditText(int resid) {
        // Find the EditText 'resid'
        EditText edittext= (EditText)mHostActivity.findViewById(resid);
        // Make the custom keyboard appear
        edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
            // NOTE By setting the on focus listener, we can show the custom keyboard when the edit box gets focus, but also hide it when the edit box loses focus
            @Override public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if( hasFocus ) showCustomKeyboard(v); else hideCustomKeyboard();
            }
        });
        edittext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            // NOTE By setting the on click listener, we can show the custom keyboard again, by tapping on an edit box that already had focus (but that had the keyboard hidden).
            @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                showCustomKeyboard(v);
            }
        });
        // Disable standard keyboard hard way
        // NOTE There is also an easy way: 'edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL)' (but you will not have a cursor, and no 'edittext.setCursorVisible(true)' doesn't work )
        edittext.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                EditText edittext = (EditText) v;
                int inType = edittext.getInputType();       // Backup the input type
                edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL); // Disable standard keyboard
                edittext.onTouchEvent(event);               // Call native handler
                edittext.setInputType(inType);              // Restore input type
                return true; // Consume touch event
            }
        });

        edittext.setInputType(edittext.getInputType() | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
    }

}
```

**My Xml File is below**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="12.50%p"
    android:keyHeight="10%p">

    <!-- android:horizontalGap="0.50%p"
    android:verticalGap="0.50%p"
    NOTE When we add a horizontalGap in pixels, this interferes with keyWidth in percentages adding up to 100%
    NOTE When we have a horizontalGap (on Keyboard level) of 0, this make the horizontalGap (on Key level) to move from after the key to before the key... (I consider this a bug) 
  -->

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="55"    android:keyLabel="7" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
        <Key android:codes="56"    android:keyLabel="8" />
        <Key android:codes="57"    android:keyLabel="9" />
         <Key android:codes="65"    android:keyLabel="A" android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popup" android:popupCharacters="aA" android:horizontalGap="6.25%p" />
        <Key android:codes="66"    android:keyLabel="B" android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popup" android:popupCharacters="bB" />
        <Key android:codes="13"    android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_delete" android:isRepeatable="true" android:horizontalGap="6.25%p" />
        <Key android:codes="55006" android:keyLabel="CLR" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="52"    android:keyLabel="4" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"  />
        <Key android:codes="53"    android:keyLabel="5" />
        <Key android:codes="54"    android:keyLabel="6" />
         <Key android:codes="67"    android:keyLabel="C" android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popup" android:popupCharacters="cC" android:horizontalGap="6.25%p" />
        <Key android:codes="68"    android:keyLabel="D" android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popup" android:popupCharacters="dD" />
        <Key android:codes="55002" android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_left" android:isRepeatable="true" android:horizontalGap="6.25%p" />
        <Key android:codes="55003" android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_right" android:isRepeatable="true" android:keyEdgeFlags="right" /> 
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="49"    android:keyLabel="1"  android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
        <Key android:codes="50"    android:keyLabel="2" />
        <Key android:codes="51"    android:keyLabel="3" />
       <Key android:codes="69"    android:keyLabel="E" android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popup" android:popupCharacters="eE"  android:horizontalGap="6.25%p" />
        NOTE We could add 'android:keyHeight="20%p"' to the 'E' key, so that it becomes twice as tall. We would then typically make the the 'done' key half the width (12.5%) but give it a double gap (25%)
        <Key android:codes="70"    android:keyLabel="F" android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popup" android:popupCharacters="fF" />
        <Key android:codes="55001" android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_allleft" android:horizontalGap="6.25%p" />
        <Key android:codes="55004" android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_allright" android:keyEdgeFlags="right" /> 
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="48"    android:keyLabel="0" android:keyWidth="25%p" android:horizontalGap="6.25%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
        <Key android:codes="-3"    android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_done" android:keyWidth="25%p" android:horizontalGap="12.50%p" />
               <Key android:codes="-5"    android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_done" android:keyWidth="25%p" android:horizontalGap="12.50%p" />
       <Key android:codes="13"    android:keyLabel="DONE" android:keyWidth="25%p" android:horizontalGap="6.25%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
        <Key android:codes="55000" android:keyLabel="PREV" android:horizontalGap="6.25%p" />
        <Key android:codes="55005" android:keyLabel="NEXT" android:keyEdgeFlags="right" /> 
    </Row>
</Keyboard>
```

**My Layout XMl file is below**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext0"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/hex"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/edittext0"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/txt"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/edittext1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/txt"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/edittext2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/hex"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/edittext3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/hex"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
        android:id="@+id/keyboardview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

`ACTION_DOWN` was not sufficient for me. You also need `ACTION_UP` right after to mimic an actual key press:

```
ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you did it (int enter = 13) wrong. Is not this way, you may try create your own code and do whatever you want when it is pressed. First, create a custom code for "DONE" button at keyboard xml. I chose number -10 for this:

```
    <Key android:codes="-10"    android:keyLabel="DONE" android:keyWidth="25%p" android:horizontalGap="6.25%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
```

Set the same code for the "enter" variable in your CustomerKeyboard class:

```
    public final static int enter = -10;
```

Now set what happens when DONE is pressed:

```
    else if(primaryCode==enter)
      {
        edittext.setText("");
        main.displayMsg();
      }
```

Sorry for my English, I hope you have understood.

Answer (score 0):

Done key action could be

```
ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
```

as written here:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615